# Как узнать роль пользователя в Enrtust. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Как узнать роль пользователя в Enrtust?
К примеру:

```
Auth::user()->*****
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пакет создает связь между таблицей ролей и таблицей пользователей.
Ей и воспользуемся:

```
$roles_collection = Auth::user()->roles;

$roles = [];

// У пользователя могут отсутствовать назначенные роли
if ($roles_collection) {
    $roles = $roles_collection->lists('name')->toArray();
}
```

Рекомендую почитать документацию по **[Eloquent: Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships)**